# C# Multiplying label text by textbox input.

Tags: c#, function, integer

I'm trying to multiply my label input by a number input into a textbox but keep running into issues...I'm also trying to keep label values unchanged if no input in textbox 3,4,5. For example if I put 3.20 in textbox 3 it will update label 1 & 4 with new value but not keep the remaining labels with original values.

Very lost...any help is much appreciated.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

*At this stage, Textbox for entering gallons becomes activated, so also a Fill button.  User enters number of gallons into the textbox and clicks Fill.
Cost of the gas order shows up in another textbox, used for display only.
Package the order price computation into a function.*

*Prices button:   renders a new set of controls visible in the lower half of the form, showing the per gallon prices for each grade of fuel [these are new controls different from the labels in the upper half, and are meant to show the manager what current prices are], and with textboxes for entering new prices for each, and two buttons, Update and Cancel in a third row. Update will update the prices read from textboxes as the new values for per gallon prices. [Note that these new values should be reflected in the labels shown below grade-of-fuel buttons in the upper half of the form. Those labels should always show the current price, so any change by Manager in prices should change those labels as well.] Cancel will change nothing. After the choice is made, the controls in the lower half disappear again.*

```
    private int gasPrice = 0;
    private int gasPrice1 = 0;
    private int gasPrice2 = 0;
    private int numGallons = 0;
    private double total = 0;
    private bool regularButton;
    private bool premiumButton;
    private bool xtraButton; 

    public Form1 ( )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void regButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        regButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
        regButton.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        textBox1.Enabled = true;

        regularButton = true;
        xtraButton = false;
        premiumButton = false; 
    }

    private void extraButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        extraButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
        extraButton.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        textBox1.Enabled = true;

        regularButton = false;
        xtraButton = true;
        premiumButton = false;
    }

    private void premButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        premButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
        premButton.ForeColor = Color.Red;

        textBox1.Enabled = true;

        regularButton = false;
        xtraButton = false;
        premiumButton = true;
    }

    private void fillButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        //double price;
        int gallons;
        int price, price1, price2;

        gasPrice = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);  
        gasPrice1 = int.Parse(label2.Text);
        gasPrice2 = int.Parse(label3.Text);
        numGallons = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        //gallons = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        //price = int.Parse(label1.Text);
        //price1 = int.Parse(label2.Text);
        //price2 = int.Parse(label3.Text);


        if (regularButton == true)
        { total = gasPrice * numGallons; }
        else if (xtraButton == true)
        { total = gasPrice1 * numGallons; }
        else
        { total = gasPrice2 * numGallons; }

        textBox2.Text = total.ToString("c");
        textBox2.Visible = true; 

        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        { MessageBox.Show("Operation Cancelled"); }
        ResetData();



    }

    private void finishButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

        ResetData();





    }

    private void ResetData ( )
    {

        //Resets buttons back to default settings
        regButton.BackColor = default(Color);
        regButton.ForeColor = default(Color);
        extraButton.BackColor = default(Color);
        extraButton.ForeColor = default(Color);
        premButton.BackColor = default(Color);
        premButton.ForeColor = default(Color);

        //Clears out both text boxes
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();

        //textboxes are returned to original state
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Visible = false;




    }

    private void salesButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // updates gas price if/when supervisor changes
        label1.Text = "$" + textBox3.Text;
        label2.Text = "$" + textBox4.Text;
        label3.Text = "$" + textBox5.Text;
        label4.Text = "$" + textBox3.Text;
        label5.Text = "$" + textBox4.Text;
        label6.Text = "$" + textBox5.Text;

    }

    private void pricesButton_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        label4.Visible = true;
        label5.Visible = true;
        label6.Visible = true;

        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;

        updateButton.Visible = true;
        cancelButton.Visible = true;
```

Comment: what issues are you running into? Please indicate specifically what help you need.

Comment: Two issues im running into...1 is trying to multiply gasPrice * numGallons, I have the gas price listed as text on the label as 3.70 and it says cannot convert string to int. 2nd issue is when typing a new value into textbox 3, it will update label 1 and 4 but in return leave labels 2,3,5,6 with just $ and not the value listed in text for the labels.

Comment: your first issue is because you are trying to convert the text from the label to an int and it is failing because you may have characters that are not numbers. Your second issue is because your code in button1_Click is updating label 1 and 4 with textbox3 and of course the other labels will just have a dollar sign if there is nothing in the textboxes for which these labels are displaying.

Comment: So I have "$3.60" in the text field and similar dollar values in the others. How do I get the "$" in my label itself but only multiply the numbers themselves for my output?

Comment: Did the answer help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

Select the textbox for which you only want to allow numeric input, in the properties window find the event (lightnig) icon and then double click the KeyPress event. That will generate a handler. Put this code in the handler:

```
if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) &&
    (e.KeyChar != '.'))
{
        e.Handled = true;
}

// only allow one decimal point
if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

That code will only allow the user to enter numbers and decimal point into the textbox.